# Remote connection using SwiftNIO SSH

Tags: ios, swift, ssh, remote-server, swift-nio

I am working on a solution that would Read/Write Server files from remote gateway system to the local storage of iOS device using SwiftNIO SSH. This way I would be able to execute shell commands. I checked in Swift's website but couldn't find specific implementation:

https://swift.org/blog/swiftnio-ssh/

How should I proceed or is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is here: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssh. There are some examples in the repository.

Comment: Please share link of any example... I tried searching this repo but didnt see any sample implementation...

Comment: Examples are in a Sources folder in main.swift files, for example: https://github.com/apple/swift-nio-ssh/blob/main/Sources/NIOSSHClient/main.swift